# Simple Electronic Signature: "Signing" PDF Without Certificate for Post-Signature Tamper-Protection

Tags: pdf, certificate, digital-signature, tcpdf, electronic-signature

First of all, a bit of background - the actual questions are at the bottom.

I'm currently working on a web-based app (sort of SaaS) which allows users to send forms to their own customers.

These forms are simple, small contracts for small jobs where their customers say "Yeah sure, I'll do this and here's my confirmation".

The sort of thing that is being "signed" does not require a fully qualified digital signature and an *electronic* signature will suffice.

While, in this case, a simple checkbox saying "Yeah, I'll do this" would legally be sufficient, I'm keen to implement it with a signature pad.  To be honest, it's just for the factor of being seemingly more binding and, well, "neat".

#### The current workflow looks like this:

1. User's customer opens web-form (the party being asked to sign is the only person in the universe to know the direct link)
2. Ticks a few boxes and enters text
3. Clicks "Sign" which opens an HTML5 signature pad (mobile) or a simple input (PC) to type their name
4. Clicks "Accept"
5. A PDF is generated for download and stored on the server (along with timestamp, IP, and a couple of other bits of information)

As you can see, the agreement in its entirety constitutes a simple electronic signature - even without the bells and whistles.

#### What I would like to do

As with any *simple* electronic signature, it's easy for any party to say that a document may have been tampered with.

So what I did is properly sign the PDF according to the specifications (using tcpdf): that entailed first generating the PDF and *then* adding the signature to the `/Sig` dictionary, then generating a digest across all byte-ranges (excluding the signature), linking it up with a `.crt` file and voilá: the document is signed with the lovely benefit of the signature becoming invalid if even a single byte is changed.

### Now to the questions:

1. Is it possible to benefit from the "tamper-validation" **without** using a certificate?  Like I say, these are not supposed to be *digital* signatures but rather simple, electronic signatures.  Still, I'd like to benefit from any post-signature changes being highlighted.
2. Alternatively, I could also simply use a proper certificate for the signing process.  But this certificate would be *mine* rather than my users' or even my users' customers'.  In that sense, would it do more harm than good? I.e. the certificate belongs to the wrong party and therefore becomes meaningless; I, rather than the signatory vouches; "The document was changed and re-signed after I signed"; etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to benefit from the "tamper-validation" without using a certificate? Like I say, these are not supposed to be digital signatures but rather simple, electronic signatures. Still, I'd like to benefit from any post-signature changes being highlighted.

No, at least as long as you want to do this in an interoperable way.

You can of course invent your own security system, create a PDF viewer or at least plugins for the commonly used PDF viewers to support your system, and roll these programs out to your users.

But if you want existing Adobe Reader as-is to verify the signature, you've got to go the X509 PKI way.

> Alternatively, I could also simply use a proper certificate for the signing process. But this certificate would be mine rather than my users' or even my users' customers'. In that sense, would it do more harm than good? I.e. the certificate belongs to the wrong party and therefore becomes meaningless; I, rather than the signatory vouches; "The document was changed and re-signed after I signed"; etc.

When using your own certificate for signing, don't forget to properly fill the reason field so it indicates that your signature is applied as a counter signature to guarantee validatability.

With that in place I don't see your signature doing any harm.

The question is how much good it does, though.

Obviously the user still can claim that he signed something different... because he did! He signed the web form, not the PDF. Thus, you might have to provide proof that the PDF reflects exactly what the web form showed anyways, that the user signed something equivalent.

If you want actual non-repudiation by the user, you need to make him sign personally in a manner that is commonly accepted to not allow tampering. In other words, your user needs to apply proper digital signatures himself. Everything else is open to claims of forgery.

Comment: Thank you for the very insightful answer! You also make a good point re. online-form vs. PDF.  While the PDF is a near pixel-perfect representation of the online form (it's an A4 document builder), you're right that they didn't actually sign the PDF.  I think, in light of all this, I will go the traditional electronic signature route alongside a sort of audit log of the user's actions that led to acceptance. Perhaps, that (possibly even the original HTML representation) could be embedded in the PDF as XML... Thanks again!

Comment: I see that providers such as RightSignature et al. also don't actually (digitally) sign documents, but rather base it around an electronic signature alongside an audit trail.  That said, they do do some hashing/digesting of sorts which I don't quite grasp how it's possible without following the PDF specs. for signatures. E.g. what byte ranges are hashed? Can an independent party re-create the hashes and check validity? etc.; also something for me to try and investigate further.

Comment: Please always keep in mind that bigger companies have had a bunch of lawyers etc inspect the flow and certified the parts that may be an issue otherwise. You might not be able to to the same...

Comment: Yes, certainly.  The purpose for which it's being designed is to gain acceptance for small-ish contracts and is merely there to "neatly" replace the usual workflow of email (being an electronic signature itself in most countries) or verbal acceptance.  I.e. it's not a signature service.  So there will be no claims around it being a "digital signature" or necessarily holding up in court in every use case scenario - any potential issues will be resolved via T&Cs/limitation of liability that'll be written up by council. Just starting to get the hang of it. Cheers again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use trusted time-stamp (defined in RFC3161) instead of signature created by the customer or by your server. Time-stamp protects document integrity and proves that your document existed before a particular time. Technically speaking it is a digital signature created by a trusted 3rd party.